# Installing PyQt4 and PyQt5 for both Python 2 and Python 3 Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, pyqt, pyside

I'm heading away for work/vacation with a macbook pro with OSX High Sierra 10.13.4 installed. I've got a series of tools to write and test. Some use PyQt4, some will need porting to PyQt5.

Can I have PyQt 4 and 5 installed for both Python 2 and 3 for OSX? If so, anyone wanna shed some light how they did it?

Would it be possible to also do this with Pyside/2 with OSX?

Comment: I'd say just go for it. It isn't to hard to uninstall everything if something goes wrong. You may want to look into [`virtualenvs`](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)

Comment: @MattM. 
It is not necessary to create a virtualenv for each package, PyQt4, PyQt5, PySide, PySide2 are independent packages that run without conflicts. for example, I have installed all the packages installed in python2 and python3.

Comment: Thanks, guys. But how would one install pyqt4 when brew doesn't allow? Are there binaries available?